# How to skew angle correction using Java

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing

I read a tutorial to give the correction of skew angle on this [site](https://felix.abecassis.me/2011/10/opencv-bounding-box-skew-angle/). But I don't understand how to convert those code to **Java**.

```
std::vector<cv::Point> points;
cv::Mat_<uchar>::iterator it = img.begin<uchar>();
cv::Mat_<uchar>::iterator end = img.end<uchar>();
for (; it != end; ++it)              
  if (*it)                           //what is the meaning of this code (1)
    points.push_back(it.pos());      //what is the meaning of this code (2)
```

Please help me understand this code.

Comment: depends which OpenCV Java implementation you are using. Are you using the native wrapper or JavaCV?

Comment: this code is equivalent to the function `findNonZero`

Comment: You may also want to look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35014061/5008845)

Comment: @thatsIch I am using native Java. I use some code (which i found) about converting BufferedImage to Mat or the opposite. I'll try the JavaCV. thanks for information.

Comment: @Miki ok, thanks for the recommendation link and explanation. I'll try it. :)

Comment: Hi @Miki, i have seen your answer it that link. I have a question in your code. what is 'swap(box.size.width, box.size.height);' mean?? I couldn't find this function in opencv (java version)

Comment: it's standard C++, exchange (swap) the content of the two variables.

Comment: @JeruJuke Please don't edit the title to include the language that is already in the tags; it's unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

For OpenCV 3.2.0 Here is full translation of deskew in Java from C++ at https://felix.abecassis.me/2011/10/opencv-bounding-box-skew-angle/ (with little modifications):

```
public Mat deskew(Mat src, double angle) {
    Point center = new Point(src.width()/2, src.height()/2);
    Mat rotImage = Imgproc.getRotationMatrix2D(center, angle, 1.0);
    //1.0 means 100 % scale
    Size size = new Size(src.width(), src.height());
    Imgproc.warpAffine(src, src, rotImage, size, Imgproc.INTER_LINEAR + Imgproc.CV_WARP_FILL_OUTLIERS);
    return src;
}

public void computeSkew( String inFile ) {
    //Load this image in grayscale
    Mat img = Imgcodecs.imread( inFile, Imgcodecs.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE );

    //Binarize it
    //Use adaptive threshold if necessary
    //Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(img, img, 255, ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, THRESH_BINARY, 15, 40);
    Imgproc.threshold( img, img, 200, 255, THRESH_BINARY );

    //Invert the colors (because objects are represented as white pixels, and the background is represented by black pixels)
    Core.bitwise_not( img, img );
    Mat element = Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_RECT, new Size(3, 3));

    //We can now perform our erosion, we must declare our rectangle-shaped structuring element and call the erode function
    Imgproc.erode(img, img, element);

    //Find all white pixels
    Mat wLocMat = Mat.zeros(img.size(),img.type());
    Core.findNonZero(img, wLocMat);

    //Create an empty Mat and pass it to the function
    MatOfPoint matOfPoint = new MatOfPoint( wLocMat );

    //Translate MatOfPoint to MatOfPoint2f in order to user at a next step
    MatOfPoint2f mat2f = new MatOfPoint2f();
    matOfPoint.convertTo(mat2f, CvType.CV_32FC2);

    //Get rotated rect of white pixels
    RotatedRect rotatedRect = Imgproc.minAreaRect( mat2f );

    Point[] vertices = new Point[4];
    rotatedRect.points(vertices);
    List<MatOfPoint> boxContours = new ArrayList<>();
    boxContours.add(new MatOfPoint(vertices));
    Imgproc.drawContours( img, boxContours, 0, new Scalar(128, 128, 128), -1);

    double resultAngle = rotatedRect.angle;
    if (rotatedRect.size.width > rotatedRect.size.height)
    {
        rotatedRect.angle += 90.f;
    }

    //Or
    //rotatedRect.angle = rotatedRect.angle < -45 ? rotatedRect.angle + 90.f : rotatedRect.angle;

    Mat result = deskew( Imgcodecs.imread( inFile ), rotatedRect.angle );
    Imgcodecs.imwrite( outputFile, result );

}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.opencv.core.*;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ValidateDocumentAlignment {

    public ValidateDocumentAlignment() {
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
    }

    public boolean isDocumentTiltAngleWithinThresholdLimit(File scannedDoc, int thresholdAngle) {
        int kernelSize = 3;
        int cannyLowerThreshold = 25;
        int cannyUpperThreshold = 50;

        Mat image = new Mat();
        Mat blur = new Mat();
        Mat edged = new Mat();
        Mat dilate = new Mat();
        Mat erode = new Mat();
        int maxValIdx = 0;
        double area = 0;
        List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<>();

        Mat sourceImage = Imgcodecs.imread(scannedDoc.getPath(), Imgcodecs.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

        Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(sourceImage, sourceImage, 255, Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY, 15, 40);
        Core.bitwise_not(sourceImage, sourceImage);
        Mat kernel = Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_RECT, new Size(kernelSize, kernelSize));
        Imgproc.morphologyEx(sourceImage, image, Imgproc.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel);
        Imgproc.GaussianBlur(image, blur, new Size(7, 7), 0);
        Imgproc.Canny(blur, edged, cannyLowerThreshold, cannyUpperThreshold);
        Imgproc.dilate(edged, dilate, kernel, new Point(-1, -1), 6);
        Imgproc.erode(dilate, erode, kernel, new Point(-1, -1), 3);
        Imgproc.findContours(erode, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

        for (int contourIdx = 0; contourIdx < contours.size(); contourIdx++) {
            Rect rect = Imgproc.boundingRect(contours.get(contourIdx));
            if ((rect.height * rect.width) > area) {
                area = rect.height * rect.width;
                maxValIdx = contourIdx;
            }
        }
        RotatedRect rotatedRect = Imgproc.minAreaRect(new MatOfPoint2f(contours.get(maxValIdx).toArray()));
        double skewAngle = rotatedRect.angle;
        int acuteAngle = (int) (skewAngle % 90);
        boolean isProperlyAligned = true;
        if (Math.abs(acuteAngle) > thresholdAngle && Math.abs(acuteAngle) < (90 - thresholdAngle)) {
            isProperlyAligned = false;
        }
        return isProperlyAligned;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private fun main(){
    val bmp:Bitmap? = null //Any bitmap (if you are working with bitmap)
    var mRgba = Mat() // else you can direct use MAT on onCameraFrame 
    val mGray = Mat()
    val bmp32: Bitmap = bmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true)
    Utils.bitmapToMat(bmp32, mRgba)
    Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba, mGray, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    mRgba = makeOrientationCorrection(mRgba,mGray)// here actual magic starts
    Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba, mGray, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    val bmpOutX = Bitmap.createBitmap(
        mRgba.cols(),
        mRgba.rows(),
        Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
    )
    Utils.matToBitmap(mRgba, bmpOutX)
    binding.imagePreview.setImageBitmap(bmpOutX!!)
}

private fun makeOrientationCorrection(mRGBA:Mat, mGRAY:Mat):Mat{
    val dst = Mat()
    val cdst = Mat()
    val cdstP: Mat
    Imgproc.Canny(mGRAY, dst, 50.0, 200.0, 3, false)
    Imgproc.cvtColor(dst, cdst, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
    cdstP = cdst.clone()

    val linesP = Mat()
    Imgproc.HoughLinesP(dst, linesP, 1.0, Math.PI/180, 50, 50.0, 10.0)

    var biggestLineX1 = 0.0
    var biggestLineY1 = 0.0
    var biggestLineX2 = 0.0
    var biggestLineY2 = 0.0
    var biggestLine = 0.0
    for (x in 0 until linesP.rows()) {
        val l = linesP[x, 0]

        Imgproc.line(
            cdstP, org.opencv.core.Point(l[0], l[1]),
            org.opencv.core.Point(l[2], l[3]),
            Scalar(0.0, 0.0, 255.0), 3, Imgproc.LINE_AA, 0)
    }

    for (x in 0 until linesP.rows()) {
        val l = linesP[x, 0]
        val x1 = l[0]
        val y1 = l[1]
        val x2 = l[2]
        val y2 = l[3]
        val lineHeight = sqrt(((x2 - x1).pow(2.0)) + ((y2 - y1).pow(2.0)))
        if(biggestLine<lineHeight){
            val angleOfRotationX1 = angleOf(PointF(x1.toFloat(),y1.toFloat()),PointF(x2.toFloat(),y2.toFloat()))
            Log.e("angleOfRotationX1","$angleOfRotationX1")
            if(angleOfRotationX1<45.0 || angleOfRotationX1>270.0){
                biggestLine = lineHeight
                if(angleOfRotationX1<45.0){
                    biggestLineX1 = x1
                    biggestLineY1 = y1
                    biggestLineX2 = x2
                    biggestLineY2 = y2
                }
                if(angleOfRotationX1>270.0){
                    biggestLineX1 = x2
                    biggestLineY1 = y2
                    biggestLineX2 = x1
                    biggestLineY2 = y1
                }
            }
        }
        if(x==linesP.rows()-1){
            Imgproc.line(
                cdstP, org.opencv.core.Point(biggestLineX1, biggestLineY1),
                org.opencv.core.Point(biggestLineX2, biggestLineY2),
                Scalar(255.0, 0.0, 0.0), 3, Imgproc.LINE_AA, 0)
        }
    }
    var angle = angleOf(PointF(biggestLineX1.toFloat(),biggestLineY1.toFloat()),PointF(biggestLineX2.toFloat(),biggestLineY2.toFloat()))
    Log.e("angleOfRotationX2","$angle")
    angle -= (angle * 2)
    return deskew(mRGBA,angle)
}

fun angleOf(p1: PointF, p2: PointF): Double {
    val deltaY = (p1.y - p2.y).toDouble()
    val deltaX = (p2.x - p1.x).toDouble()
    val result = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX))
    return if (result < 0) 360.0 + result else result
}

private fun deskew(src:Mat, angle:Double):Mat{
    val center = org.opencv.core.Point((src.width() / 2).toDouble(), (src.height() / 2).toDouble())
    val scaleBy = if(angle<0){
        1.0+((0.5*angle)/45)//max scale down by 0.50(50%) based on angle
    }else{
        1.0-((0.3*angle)/45)//max scale down by 0.50(50%) based on angle
    }

    Log.e("scaleBy",""+scaleBy)
    val rotImage = Imgproc.getRotationMatrix2D(center, angle, scaleBy)
    val size = Size(src.width().toDouble(), src.height().toDouble())
    Imgproc.warpAffine(src, src, rotImage, size, Imgproc.INTER_LINEAR + Imgproc.CV_WARP_FILL_OUTLIERS)
    return src
}
```