# Detect image skew angle using a single central line in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, skew

Having rather rudimentary understanding of both Python and OpenCV, I have tough time finding a solution to deskew some of my pictures, as most examples I have found only use page edges as markers, which are not visible in my case. However, there is always a "central" vertical line that I think I can use, like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDGbX.jpg

What I would like to do is to find this line—I guess using Hough Line Transform?—but only this line (discarding any other potential lines) and calculate the angle between it's extreme points to apply deskew algorithms.

How can that be done in Python?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35014061/5008845). First step is deskewing, and could be easily applied to your image, too

Comment: Thanks, @Miki, I will try to map this into Python. Seems a bit of a circular logic—deskewing as preparation for deskewing…

Comment: Don't mind me, it's just that I found your "first step is deskewing" statement a bit odd, but nevertheless helpful, kind sir :)