# python segment an image of text line by line

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to segment the below Burmese text image line by line (ultimately syllable by syllable, but one step at a time) by looking at the sum of black pixel in each row (Attached plot along with the code used to produce it). How can I go about segmenting text images as such using using sum of black pixels info?

Edit: Notice the lines are very close to each other so I'm having some trouble segmenting using cv2 dilation/erosion/findcontour. I have tried the method in [Split text lines in scanned document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34981144/split-text-lines-in-scanned-document) too as @Miki suggested. 
In the text image, there are total of 6 lines of text. Possibly due to how burmese text characters look, I keep getting both over/under segmentation. Thus, I finally resorted to just making a decision based on sum of black pixels in each row.

[TextImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zk2Vg.png)

[PlotOfBlkPixelSumByRow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhAfP.png)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2


image = cv2.imread('TextImage.PNG')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
cv2.imshow('binary',thresh)
cv2.waitKey(0)

thresh_sum = thresh.sum(axis=1)
plt.plot(thresh_sum)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Consider the global minimas, where frequency is absolutely zero as a segmentation point.