# Image Cropping using canny edges detection

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, canny-operator

I have generated the edges using Canny edge detector now want to crop source image by those edges.

Is there any way to get.

1. Left and Top Most `255` pixel location of image.
2. Right and Top Most `255` pixel location of image.
3. Left and Bottom Most `255` pixel location of image.
4. Right and Bottom Most `255` pixel location of image.

And crop that image based on that location. 
Using open cv or any other library using python.

Comment: `cv2.findNonZero` and `cv2.boundingRect` on the result.

Comment: If pixel [1,2] and [2,1] are both white, which is the left and topmost?

Comment: Something like that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34981144/split-text-lines-in-scanned-document/48268334#48268334?

Comment: @Silencer yes, please mark it as a duplicate. I have also marked

Answer (score 0):

There may be better solutions but I think you can implement an algorithm.

Start by drawing a square that FULLY captures the child set of pixels. Then, slowly bringing in the sides one at a time until they encounter a `255` pixel. Once you've fully pulled in all 4 sides, you will have your desired area to crop.

You could also use four simple (one-liner) **For loop**s to check for *"first white pixel"*. Since pixels x-pos starts at top/left, Using `x++` to check forward and `x--` to check backwards (from right-side).